# Post gallery loop with thumb and full size

Tags: gallery

So the goal is to have a href to the full size image and the img src to be the thumbnail.

Up till no i have this

```
 <?php $gallery = get_post_gallery_images();
    foreach($gallery as $img){ ?>
        <div class="galerija-box">
            <a href="<?php echo $img ?>" rel="lightbox"><img src="<?php echo $img ?>"/></a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

This only gives me the image sizes the user selects when inserting the gallery into the post.

Any ideas How I could have different urls for the a href and img src?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be other possibilities to this, mine is given below ..

1. First you use the `get_post_gallery` function to store the image id's in a separate array ..

   ```
   if ( get_post_gallery() ) {

       $gallery        = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
       $galleryIDS[]   = array();

       /* Loop through all the image and store them one by one */
       foreach( $gallery['ids'] as $ids ) {

           $galleryIDS[] = $ids;

       }
   }
   ```
2. Then you output each image by id using `wp_get_attachment_image` as shown below ..

   ```
   <?php foreach ($galleryIDS as $key => $value ) { ?>

       <div class="galerija-box">
               <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $value, 'medium' ) ?>"  rel="lightbox">
                   <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $value, 'full' ) ?>"/>
               </a>
       </div>
   <?php } ?>
   ```

I didn't test the code so it might have some syntax issues, but the method should work for you ..

**EDIT**

As mentioned before I didn't check the code if its functional or not. So I tested it out, found a few bugs, fixed them. Below is the working code ..

```
if ( get_post_gallery() ) {

    $gallery        = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
    $galleryIDS     = $gallery['ids'];
    $pieces         = explode(",", $galleryIDS);

    foreach ($pieces as $key => $value ) { 

        $image_medium   = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $value, 'medium'); 
        $image_full     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $value, 'full'); 
    ?>


    <div class="galerija-box">
            <a href="<?php echo $image_medium[0] ?>"  rel="lightbox">
                <img src="<?php echo $image_full[0] ?>"/>
            </a>
    </div>
    <?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Comment: this looks like a lot of sense :), I mean yea will try it and let you know, but i think this is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer to close this thread when you test it out. Thanks ..

Comment: var_dump($galleryIDS);
returns zero results... :)

Comment: Edited the answer ..

Comment: You're calling `get_post_gallery()` twice, I'm sure you can modify it so it's only called once ;-)

Comment: The `get_post_gallery()` function in if statement checks if there is a gallery in the post

Comment: yap did the same on my own :) but yea thats the solution, thanks a lot